# local ansible-playbook run playbook with vars for role

Tags: ansible

I'm pretty new to ansible so I might be setting up things wrong. My idea is I have certain classes of servers. (monitor,web,db for example)

I want to run a local ansible run on them so my play for monitor looks something like

```
---

# plays/monitor.yaml

- hosts: mongo
  connection: local
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - ../roles/users
    - ../roles/monitor
  vars:
    sensu_install_client: true
    sensu_install_server: true
```

My `roles/monitor/tasks/main.yml` looks like

```
---

# roles/monitor/tasks/main.yaml

- include: common.yml

- include: server.yml
  when: sensu_install_server

- include: client.yml
  when: sensu_install_client
```

I want to be able to pass in vars so includes will happen in the role. So when I setup my api instances I can do something like

```
vars:
   sensu_install_client: true
```

In the play and it will just include the client.yml from the monitor role.

Comment: Are you having problems with this setup or is your question if the setup can be improved?

Comment: Both I guess.. when I run the playbook via `ansible-playbook plays/monitor.yml` It doesn't run anything in the monitor/tasks/server.yml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear to me why this is not working. I can't see a problem. But let me give you some general recommendations, maybe that'll help you too.

Best practice is to have your playbooks on the root level. Have a look at [this structure](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout). With that setup, you do not need to specify the path to the roles as Ansible automatically expects roles in the `roles` directory relative to the playbook. Then your roles section in the playbook is much cleaner:

```
roles:
  - users
  - monitor
```

Instead of defining global variables to trigger actions inside roles you can use two other approaches.

#### 1. role parameters

Roles can have parameters. If you want to pass parameters you simply have to convert it to a dictionary:

```
roles:
  - users
  - role: monitor
    sensu_install_client: true
    sensu_install_server: true
```

The variables `sensu_install_client` and `sensu_install_server` then are available only in the role `monitor`. This is a litte more cleaner and also makes it clear to anybody these vars will be used in this role, not in the `users` role.

#### 2. tags

Tags actually are the way how to trigger specific parts of a playbook/roles. Tags though are passed from the command line and not by hardcoded variables in the playbook. Imagine your role `main.yml` looks like this:

```
---

# roles/monitor/tasks/main.yaml

- include: common.yml
  tags: always

- include: server.yml
  tags: server

- include: client.yml
  tags: client
```

The tag `always` is special and will run the tagged tasks... well you guessed it... always.

Now you would call your playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook monitor.yml --tags server
```

or

```
ansible-playbook monitor.yml --tags client
```

Or if you want to run both you even could do:

```
ansible-playbook monitor.yml --tags "client,server"
```

If you use this, don't forget to tag your users role accordingly, or it will not be ran at all.

If you do not specify any `--tags` all tasks are executed, if you want to filter specific tags you can use the `--skip-tags` option

```
ansible-playbook monitor.yml --skip-tags "server"
```

You could even filter the always tag.

```
ansible-playbook monitor.yml --tags "server" --skip-tags "always"
```

Comment: thanks that helped a lot.. I think the root of the issue was the play was called monitor.yaml and the role was also monitor so not sure if there's some python import namespacing going on but once i renamed the monitor role to sensu it cleared up.